# How can I remove the margin from CSS?

Tags: html, css, margin

I a beginner with Stack Overflow, with HTML and CSS. Sorry if does not look like to a standard question.

I am trying to build a website. I see that I have two margins (one on the left side and another one on the right side of the screen). I would like to have *no* margin. What is wrong in my code?

[image]

My CSS code is

```css
.container
{
    /* Center contents */
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.table
{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}

main .form-control
{
    /* Center form controls */
    display: inline-block;

    /* Override Bootstrap's 100% width for form controls */
    width: auto;
}

main
{
    /* Scroll horizontally as needed */
    overflow-x: auto;

    /* Center contents */
    text-align: center;
}


main td
{
    /* Left-align the tables' cells */
    text-align: left;
}
```

I added the HTML code as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport"/>

        <title>My Finance: {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span class="blue">My</span><span class="red">Finance</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                        {% if session.user_id %}
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('quote') }}">Quote</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('buy') }}">Buy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('sell') }}">Sell</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('history') }}">History</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Log Out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        {% else %}
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Log In</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            {% if get_flashed_messages() %}
                <header>
                    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                        {{ get_flashed_messages() | join(" ") }}
                    </div>
                </header>
            {% endif %}

            <main>
                {% block main %}{% endblock %}
            </main>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best way will be to inspect element with browser tools. Otherwise please add HTML too.

Comment: add the html code too

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor. (With just the CSS and no HTML you've given, that looks like the margin you **explicitly gave to an element** so don't do that if you don't want that).

Comment: Without HTML or a [mcve] it's virtually impossible to figure out from just the CSS and a screenshot

Comment: I just added the html code

Comment: Right, now we need the CSS for the navbar. The only relevant thing you included in your CSS was for `.container`

Comment: HI @phuzi I didn't write a code for the navbar. Is it the issue you think?

Comment: Yep, since that's where the margins are that you're asking about. I'm guessing you're using something like Bootstrap.

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap try changing `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">` for full width

Comment: thanks a lot! it was the issue, it's good now !

Comment: What is the templating engine (e.g., `{% endblock %}`)? [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC)? [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29), in which case you should change

```
<div class="container">
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

because the `container` class has a fixed width, but `container-fluid` is full width. This should remove any extra padding/margin that your page has.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try doing a CSS "reset":

```css
* {margin: 0;}
```

This will get rid of margins everywhere. If you need a margin somewhere in the future, you can set it on that specific element.

2. Try setting `width: 100%` on that element that you're seeing margins on.

[MetropolisCZ's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940342/how-to-remove-the-margin-from-css#comment121837636_68940342) on using the Dev Tools is also excellent advice.

Comment: Hi, I tried your proposition but the issue is still the same.

Answer (score -1):

Add a reset style to your code:

```css
* { 
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box; 
   }
```

Comment: That's a horrible sledgehammer approach, and one I don't think will work here given the rest of the CSS provided

Comment: I tried your proposition but the issue is still the same.